# WCF Data Service with Customer class

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service with an EDMX model as data source.

I have 2 tables in my EDMX, `Customer` and `Order List` which are connected by a one-to-many relationship: a `Customer` can have many `Orders`.

My requirement is that I want to return a customer along with all the orders he placed.

I tried by creating a custom class for `Customer` which is has a `List<OrderList>` property. But I am unable to return the custom class from my WCF Data Service.

While doing so I am getting below error -

> Request Error Request Error The server encountered an error
>   processing the request.  The exception message is 'Unable to load
>   metadata for return type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[CustomerWithOrders]' of method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[CustomerWithOrders]
>   GetCustomerWithOrders(int customerID)'

Can’t we return any custom classes with a WCF Data Service?

Can we have two data sources for a single WCF Data Service?

Is there any way of creating an entity in EDMX which is having a complex type property of list type of some other entity?

EX. **Customer Entity**

- `custID` – normal property
- `custAdd` - normal property
- `custTel` – normal property
- `List<OrderList>` – complex property of type List of OrderList entity

**OrderList Entity**

- `Ordered` - normal property
- `custID` – normal property
- `orderDesc` – normal property

Or is there any other way to solve this kind of problem.

Please help I am stuck.